# Creating a trigger to update multiple records after insert sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Well basically I need this trigger to work after a user inserts multiple records into the database. So that when an optionID of 0 is inserted and the IsoptionalID = 1, then set the OptionID = NULL

```
CREATE TRIGGER ThisDatabase
   ON  OtherTable
  AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN

DECLARE @OPTIONID INT
SET @OPTIONID = OtherTable.OPTIONID

DECLARE @ISoptional INT
SET @ISoptional = OtherTable.ISoptional

        CASE @optionID WHEN  0 and @ISoptional = 1 set update  OtherTable set optionid = null end
END
```

I am not sure about the case itself either.

Thank you in advance

Comment: What is the trigger supposed to do? You appear to be missing bits of the code too..

Comment: What is the definition of the table? Including PK definition?

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the key field(s) of the table, but SQL Server triggers always work on the entire data set being modified (Inserted, Updated, or Deleted).  So the trigger would something more like:

```
CREATE TRIGGER ThisDatabase
   ON  OtherTable
  AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON

   UPDATE ot
   SET    ot.OptionID = NULL
   FROM   OtherTable ot
   INNER JOIN INSERTED ins
           ON ins.KeyField = ot.KeyField
   WHERE   ins.OptionID = 0
   AND     ins.IsOptional = 1

END
```

The INSERTED table has the rows that were either Inserted or Updated (current version).
The DELETED table has the rows that were either Deleted or Updated (old version).

So, the INSERTED and DELETED tables are pre-filtered to only the changed records, but they are not updatable (since the event already happened due to this being an AFTER trigger and SQL Server not having a BEFORE trigger) so you need to do the UPDATE on the real table.

Comment: so what are the key values you are specifying, and the inserted?

Comment: Not key VALUES, key FIELDS. You need to JOIN the INSERTED table to the real table based on the fields that uniquely identify each row. Also, the INSERTED table is exactly that name. The only things to change in the above code are "OtherTable" and "KeyField".

Answer (score 0):

It isn't really clear what you want to do, but here's a skeleton. Just note:

- Triggers are created on the table which is being affected (not an `Other table`)
- You can certainly update another table as a consequence of a trigger. This is typically done through a join.
- Use the `inserted` and `deleted` pseudo-tables to identify the record(s) which have been inserted, updated or deleted.

  ```
  CREATE TRIGGER TR_TableBeingInsertedInto
     ON  TableBeingInsertedInto
     AFTER INSERT
  AS 
  BEGIN
       UPDATE OtherTable
       -- What you actually want to do here isn't clear to me
           SET OtherTable.OPTIONID = 
               CASE i.OptionID
                 WHEN 0 THEN NULL
                 ELSE OtherTable.OPTIONID
               END
           FROM OtherTable
               -- Inserted has the same schema as TableBeingInsertedInto
               INNER JOIN INSERTED i                  
                  ON OtherTable.SomeCommonKey = i.SomeCommonKey;
  END
  ```